# OpenCL: Conversion from 'int *' to '__generic int *__generic *'

Tags: c, opencl

I want to implement a pipe in OpenCL 2.0 between two kernels. However the compilation of the kernel fails because of the conversion of the arguments:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'write_pipe'
write_pipe(outputPipe, &value);
^~~~~~~~~~
note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'int *' to '__generic int *__generic *' for 2nd argument
note: candidate function not viable: requires 4 arguments, but 2 were provided
```

The producer kernel is very simple:

```
__kernel void pipe_kernel(__write_only pipe int *outputPipe) {
  int value = 1;
  write_pipe(outputPipe, &value);
}
```

The interface of the write_kernel function:

```
int write_pipe (pipe gentype p, const gentype  *ptr)
```

The pipe in the host code is set up to work with integer:

```
cl_mem pipe = clCreatePipe(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, sizeof(int), elements, NULL, &status);
clSetKernelArg(pipe_kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), &pipe);
```

Is there a generic address space that has to be considered for pipes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `pipe` kernel argument is declared as a pointer:

```
__write_only pipe int *outputPipe
```

It should just be:

```
__write_only pipe int outputPipe
```